# How to make actual dots on a slick slideshow?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js

How do I make actual dots on the slideshow as I currently just get buttons with numbers on them. I have no idea how to do this, or where to put it. Can anyone help? The code on my site is exactly what I was told to do on a site, but it doesn't work. This is a brand new site that has not yet been published anywhere.

```css
#slideshow .slick-slide { min-height: 1180px;
}

#slideshow .slick-dots {
    transform: translateY(-50);
     position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
  bottom: 50px;
display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 
 margin: 0;
 padding: 1rem 0;
 
 list-style-type: none;
 
  li {
   margin: 0 0.25rem;
  }
 
  button {
   display: block;
   width: 1rem;
   height: 1rem;
   padding: 0;
   
   border: none;
   border-radius: 100%;
   background-color: blue;
   
   text-indent: -9999px;
  }
 
  li.slick-active button {
   background-color: red;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="slideshow">
     <div style="background:url(CSS/Images/SunnyBistro-7%20edited.jpg) center no-repeat; background-size:cover;">
         <div class="slider-content">
            <h2> Slider Title 1</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum </p>
            </div>
        </div>
     <div style="background:url(CSS/Images/Gaming-3.jpeg) center no-repeat; background-size:cover;">
         <div class="slider-content">
            <h2> Slider Title 2</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/stickynavbar.js/1.3.4/jquery.stickyNavbar.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.3.15/slick.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.header ').stickyNavbar();
 $('#slideshow').slick({
dots: true,
  infinite: true,
  speed: 500,
  fade: true,
  cssEase: 'linear',
arrows: false,
autoplay:true,
autoplayspeed: 2000,
         

});

    })
</script>
```

[image]

Comment: We are no magical creature who would know everything.  Please provide a proper  [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Border radius and text indent

Comment: You need to add you code...

Comment: Sorry you guys, I've added the code in now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to add:

[slick.css](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.3.13/slick.css)

slick-theme.css